# How to save environment variable on my Ubuntu Linux system

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, shell, environment-variables

I am using Maven to the build process of my Java project.

To launch the mvn command in any position within the shell I am using the following command to declare the environment variable in this way:

**export MAVEN_HOME=/home/andrea/SpringSource/apache-maven-3.0.4**

**export PATH=$PATH:$MAVEN_HOME/bin**

The problem is that if I close my shell, when I open it again I have to give again the previous commands...how can I solve this problem and "save" the environment variable on my system?

Thank you

Andrea

Answer (score 2):

You should save these commands as lines in your `~/.bashrc` file. That way, these commands are applied/run each time you start a new instance of bash, i.e. each time you log in.

Otherwise:

- To make the variables system-wide, disregarding which shell you use, assign the variables in `/etc/environment` (as described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#System-wide_environment_variables)) (alternatively in `/etc/profiles`).
- To make the variables system-wide for bash (for all users using bash), place the lines in the file `/etc/bash.bashrc` (alternatively in `/etc/bashrc` on some other OSes than Ubuntu)

Comment: Note, you cannot use variables in `/etc/environment`, so `$MAVEN_HOME`, `$PATH` will not work. Only static values.